# How to embed google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to add a Google Map to my website, and I tried this:

```
 $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", function () {
     alert("1");          
     var map;
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     alert("2");
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("container"), myOptions);
 });
```

This is not working. Can anybody tell me why?

**EDIT**

Script loaded perfectly. I know this because `alert(1)` shows but after that control does not reach `alert(2)`.

Comment: Nobody can tell you why it's not working, since nobody has any idea how it is not working until you actually tell us.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? If you mean no error occurs and it simply doesn't show up, first I would investigate the value of `id` and make sure it exists. Then go from there.

Comment: Paste your html code, the element with the id `id` must be a `div` with height and width specified.

Comment: Now may be my edit can explain my problem clearly !

Comment: Have you checked with a browser debug tool if you get any unexpected script errors? If you use Chrome/Firefox, CTRL+SHIFT+J for example. Maybe some syntax is incorrect.

Comment: i am using chrome and when i press ctrl+shift+j it shows me `uncaught typeerror: undefined is not a function` just after `new google.maps.latlang(..)`

Comment: It seems that your `LatLng` call is not a valid call in the given situation. Have you tried `samsamX` suggestion of separating out the declaration of retrieving the `LatLng`? Maybe that gets rid of the error.

Comment: yes i tried that also but not works

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

What is **id**, where did that get defined?

Also getScript is for doing Ajax requests, which isn't really how you should be doing Google Maps.  Just call the script in the normal way, and have an init function which executes on document ready.  Or even better use the window.load event listener that the Google Maps API provides for you anyway.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function init(id) 
     {          
             var map;
             var myOptions = {
                 zoom: 8,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             };
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), myOptions);
     }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init('yourDivID'));
</script>
```

Comment: @tkone: Only guessing. I would assume as it was a question only before the last edit. Might have been more appropriate as a comment in that case? Unless off course it was very obvious that this was the cause of the issue. Then it should have been a definite answer and not a question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use async loading for this - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch

In the current approach, the script do this-

```
function getScript(src) {
  document.write('<' + 'script src="' + src + '"' + ' type="text/javascript"><' + '/script>');
}
```

So, when you call `$.getScript`, that will goto void. And, `google.maps.LatLng` becomes undefined.

I've created a version with the async one. You can check the fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/rifat/G3yPw/

Comment: let me know if you want to know why the `alert(2)` didn't invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on your container div.

It must have specified width and height.

And I used to separate the affectation of LatLng :

```
     var map;
     var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: ll,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("container"), myOptions);
```